# Catching Incoming call events in flutter+android

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, telephony

I have been having some problem understanding the some concepts related to Android `BroadcastReceiver`. My goal is to listen to incoming calls in the background (i.e. when the app is not running). Also I am coding in Flutter, so I have created a *flutter plugin*.
There is already a library that does it for SMSs : [telephony](https://pub.dev/packages/telephony). I have studied the code of the aforementioned plugin. There is a `IncomingSmsReceiver` which extends `BroadcastReceiver` which receives all sms and processes it accordingly (when the app is in background or not running , it creates an `Isolate` and runs a user specified callback inside that isolate).

Another thing to notice is that the `IncomingSmsReceiver` runs in a different process whenever I close the app, as evident by the following lines from `adb logcat`

```
D Zygote  : Forked child process 6287
I ActivityManager: Start proc 6287:org.sudipta.sms_handler_example/u0a525 for broadcast {org.sudipta.sms_handler_example/com.shounakmulay.telephony.sms.IncomingSmsReceiver}
```

This child process is forked **only** when I close my app. I am not sure how this behavior is achieved. Can anyone please help me on this? I am not sure if its flutter specific behavior or if its some cofig in the `BroadcastReceiver` itself.

There are lots of material in the internet regarding how to keep the broadcast receiver running (using `Service`). But the **telephony** plugin does not seem to use any Service to keep the Receiver running. I am just trying to understand how the Receiver is being run on a different process when I close my application.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not fully clear to me. But I think `flutter_call_kit` or `flutter_incoming_call` plugins can help you

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want to get the incoming call number, when my app is closed (much like truecaller) and process it further. My broadcast receiver does not work when the app is not running. While the **telephony** successfully receives Sms even when the app is closed. What I have found is that whenever I close my app, somehow the broadcast receiver of the telephony plugin starts running in a different process. I am not sure how it is doing that. The plugin does not use any `Service`.